# codexample.org appears to be replicating Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, plagiarism, copycat-sites

I've noticed that the Stack Overflow question [No sound issue kills audio for all apps on the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40533019/no-sound-issue-kills-audio-for-all-apps-on-the-device) has been replicated on a different website: [[Ios] No sound issue kills audio for all apps on the device - CodExample](https://codexample.org/questions/732320/no-sound-issue-kills-audio-for-all-apps-on-the-device.c) and I wanted to report this.

I found this on a Google search for "ios coreaudio nan".

*(Perhaps SO is already aware of codexample.org but I wasn't sure where to report this.)*

Comment: And at least there you can upvote, refresh, and upvote again (and again and again and again) :)

Comment: Surely a site named CodExample should just contain images of fish?

Comment: lol https://media.giphy.com/media/rLGth4SQsazsY/giphy.gif

Comment: It's expertsexchange.com all over again...

Comment: lol first time I saw the vote count was ten in codexample.. Now its 7.. [meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect) gone weird?

Comment: I just went to downvote and the votes went from -17 to -22 for the question and -11 to -16 for the answer, they're racking up fast. Edit 1 minute later, now its at -153 ^^

Comment: Seems there are a lot of people who love down-voting. Already at -300.

Comment: Downvote + refresh + downvote + refresh + downvote + refresh...

Comment: @programmer5000 `while true; do curl https://codexample.org/api/v1/questions/732320/vote/vote_down >/dev/null; done` ;)

Comment: @Siguza I predict a DDOS

Comment: @PaulMasri-Stone If we can get the score to underflow... worth it. :P

Comment: @Siguza that would be terrible, it's score could wrap to be so high!

Comment: If you are faster in mouse click then till ajax call you can give 5 downvote in single refresh otherwise .Downvote and refresh , downvote and refresh and key part is we can do it without login.  ;)

Comment: We need to use this as an example of how not broken SO voting is :)

Comment: @NickA ...or their database crashes. :)

Comment: @NathanOliver and why to never mess with the meta crowd. :P

Comment: And it keeps getting better: [CodExample Terms of Service](https://codexample.org/terms-of-service): *All pages, contents and graphics (except advertisements and other company logo) on this web site are the property of CodExample website. Codes and other information provided here may not be redistributed or reproduced in any way, or form without the written permission of CodExample. Any violation will be the violation of copyright laws.*

Comment: _For science only:_ in js console: `for(i=0;i<50;i++) { $('.vote-down').trigger('click') }` seems to be working... *remember* no DoS intended! I wonder how far is an `OutOfRangeException` is really...

Comment: [Curl is faster](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351836/codexample-org-appears-to-be-replicating-stack-overflow?noredirect=1#comment488958_351836)

Comment: @programmer5000 only if you have Curl :)

Comment: @programmer5000 except that JS is natively supported by most modern browsers...

Comment: @NickA it's availible on windows

Comment: You can downvote AND upvote too (even without a refresh). You know for when you just can't decide...

Comment: `for ((i=1; i<=999999; i++)); do curl https://codexample.org/api/v1/questions/$i/vote/vote_dow‌​n ; curl https://codexample.org/api/v1/answers/$i/vote/vote_dow‌​n ; done;` DOWNVOTE THEM ALL

Comment: what does favoriting do though? do you actually get notifications?

Comment: @programmer5000 replace those `;` with `&` ;P

Comment: This is the best meta effect I have ever seen. Poor Jim...

Comment: @Bugs don't worry... Pretty sure jim doesn't have a cod example account ^^

Comment: How do we log bugs with them? I'd like to log the fact there is no separator for the vote count on answers. I'm just finding it too difficult to read.

Comment: @Bugs [This site](https://codeide.co/terms-of-service) lists the same contact email and the domain has no whois guard... you could send a letter to Vietnam... :)

Comment: And oh look, he has [yet another website](https://w3stacks.com/questions/maven/93476/how-to-copy-resources-from-other-module-to-specific-location-maven) that [rips off Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2957048) (see [old whois data](http://www.siteleaks.com/www.w3stacks.com) for accountability).

Comment: @Siguza -1 for posting a SO clone without a voting feature implemented... so we can't distribute our _voting culture_

Comment: @suraj lol at the name ^^

Comment: yeah thats what reminded me http://www.siteleaks.com/www.weslack.com actual site http://www.weslack.com/question/1298200000003060557

Comment: @Siguza You reported the w3stacks.com site to SO too?

Comment: @PaulMasri-Stone nope, too lazy right now.

Comment: Bad @Siguza, bad! I've reported it now. 

Comment: Wow, you all are having a little bit too much fun.  Score of -30,700 right now. :D

Comment: FWIW, I wrote an article and helped Stack Overflow! Ha ha, evil minds: [Best way to punish Plagiarisers? DDoS attack them!](https://blog.praveen.science/best-way-to-punish-plagiarisers-ddos-attack-them/). Trust me, teaching people by trolling that guys was the best thing and so much fun!

Comment: @PaulMasri-Stone You are right! ^^^ I took it personal! 

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question it was closed as, so I have reopened it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can actually report it here: https://stackoverflow.com/contact.

Choose "Stackexchange content is being reproduced without attribution" from the dropdown and set the links in the form.
I had found a couple of similar sites.

Comment: FYI I've reported it as suggested. Thanks.

Comment: @PaulMasri-Stone FWIW, I wrote an article and helped Stack Overflow! Ha ha, evil minds: [Best way to punish Plagiarisers? DDoS attack them!](https://blog.praveen.science/best-way-to-punish-plagiarisers-ddos-attack-them/). Trust me, teaching people by trolling that guys was the best thing and so much fun!